# Arduino 3.3v pro mini, most efficient use of AA batteries for power

Tags: battery, arduino-pro-mini

I want to use a 3.3V pro mini that uses a BME 280 to take temp/pressure/humidity, and nRF24L01 module to transmit the data, at ?10 minute intervals. I want to use 1, 2,3 or 4  AA batteries to power it. I've read all about the techniques to reduce power consumption, by removing the power LED and using sleep functions.
But I would like to know the most efficient combination of batteries to use. If I can get a year out of 1 battery and a step-up converter, I would be happiest with that. But perhaps 3 duracell or 4 (rechargeable) batteries  connected directly to the Vcc pin (ie no regulator) might be better. Does anyone have first-hand experience to know what works best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do better with another regulator that the on-board ones, which are not energy efficient because they drop the supply voltage through a resistance, wasting the excess current as heat. An external boost regulator would waste much less current (charge, really, since we're trying to make maximum use of the battery capacity, or equivalently, trying to minimize the capacity & space needed to run your system for a year).

So you need two things:

1. The most space-efficient way (I assume...) to store a year's energy needs; and
2. A pretty good idea of what the energy requirement will be.

For (2.), you'll need an energy budget for your system:

1. How much current your system draws when it is awake;
2. How much current your system draws when it is asleep;
3. It's duty cycle (e.g.: 3% awake time, 97% sleep time), and use that to calculate the total charge in milliAmp-hours the system draws during the 1 year.

Don't forget to account for the batteries' inefficiency when they're cold, if that will be an issue, and add in a safety factor so it won't die before you arrive a year hence to change the batteries.

You'll need to consider powering down the sensor(s) and radio(s) during CPU sleep; their idle draw would make sleeping the CPU ineffective (as far as saving battery is concerned).

Once you have an energy budget, you can look at the available ways to store and deliver a year's worth - regulator type, size and efficiency; battery size and count) to see what combination will meet your needs for cost, simplicity, and space limitations.